# Непонятные минусы на вопрос "Что это за числа: 0x10, 0o10, 010, 0b10?"

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, нытьё

Есть вопрос: [Что это за числа в JavaScript: 1e10, 0x10, 0o10, 010, 0b10? Числовые литералы в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1419445/)

Поискал в Google, не нашёл похожих вопросов, создал свой. Некоторое время спустя после создания вопроса, прилетели минусы на вопрос (На данный момент голоса такие: `0 / -4`), а вот откуда и почему непонятно, тут и назревает сам вопрос:

За что минусы? Вопрос, очевидно отражает стремление разобраться (я сам на него ответил). Он понятен (всё что нужно написать в ответе, я описал в вопросе). Он явно несёт пользу, ведь до этого вопросов по литеральным числам не было (в общем о них, а не конкретные литералы, для примера только восьмеричные литералы).

Для меня остаётся только одна причина. Вопрос был до этого закрыт как дубликат, а уже сами участники не захотели разбираться и без разбору поставили минусы. Если я сделал что-то не так, то прошу прояснить мне причины минусов, т.к. я их в упор не вижу.

#### Обновление

После вопроса прилетело очень много голосов "за", спасибо всем кто голосовал за вопрос и/или ответ! (Текущий показатель `+14 / -5`)

Comment: Голосовал за переоткрытие, ну хрюнди всё равно закрыл))

Comment: Хороший вопрос и ответ, плюсанул.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский только что заново осмотрел "оригинальный" вопрос, кажется что Grundy хочет отобрать часть моего пирога :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Самое прикольное то, что я именно текущий топик более подходящий по названию "числа начинающиеся с нуля" :D Т.к. он более обширный. А вот **тот** скорее бы надо переименовать в более узкий формат

Comment: А я все думаю, кто тут минусует...

Comment: @ksa, и кто же?

Comment: @insolor, у меня не показывается "кто".

Comment: @ksa к чему тогда комментарий "А я все думаю, кто тут минусует..."? Выглядит так, как будто вы вычислили этих нехороших людей)

Comment: @insolor, извини что не верно тебя ввел в такое заблуждение. Я даже не возражаю чтобы мои комментарии удалили, раз они внесли такую сумятицу по этому вопросу.

Comment: @ksa, да мне все равно в общем-то, просто интересно

Comment: @insolor, теперь ты меня ввел в заблуждение. Поскольку тем кому все равно ведут себя иначе.

Comment: @ksa скажем так, мне стало любопытно, что означал тот комментарий, но мне все равно, будут ли удалены комментарии или нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142086/discussion-between-ksa-and-insolor).

Comment: Благодаря этому вопросу, я узнал, что на мете есть метка `нытьё` =).

Comment: @Зонтик не благодарите :)